# My Mac is not taking my Heap Size configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, heap-memory

I'm trying to work with thousands of live objects on my Mac. I tried to change the heap size in the `eclipse.ini` to 2G but according to my jconsole Java is still limiting to 130mb and throwing Java Heap Space error out of memory.

It seems that Java doesn't take my parameters.

I would share some screen shots for further details. Like jconsole data ini file and error message.

Thanks in advance you all.

```
Eclipse.ini =>>

-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-d64
-XX:PermSize: 512m
-XX:MaxPermSize: 2048m
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM that is having memory error (running your Java application) is not the same JVM that runs your Eclipse. To set the memory constraint for your application, you need to use Eclipse's Run Configuration dialog (under Arguments tab -> VM Arguments) to set the memory constraint (sorry I can't post images yet!)

Comment: Ken Lai, you were completly right! I changed for: -d64  -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms512m. The program works and I monitored thru Console and is handling with more  than 1,5G of live objects now. Thank you very much.